# Custom user-roles and -permissions in installation script

Tags: php, drupal, installation, drupal-7

Is it possible to write some code in your `.install`-file of your D7 website which allows you to generate user roles and permissions automatically? I always though so, but right now, I can't think of a way to do it.
Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely:

```
function mymodule_install() {
  // Make the new role
  $role = new stdClass;
  $role->name = 'new role name';
  $role->weight = 3;
  user_role_save($role);

  // Permissions to assign to the role.
  // Note these are defined in hook_permission()
  $perms = array(
    'access administration pages',
    'view content',
    'any other permission you want'
  );

  // Grant the permissions. This function takes care of all necessary cache resets
  user_role_grant_permissions($role->rid, $perms);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and correct reply! I assume it something similar like this? http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/getting-started-drupal-install-profiles

Comment: How do I get the values of the permissions in the array? A simple `var_dump($perms)`?

Comment: That link is for Drupal 6 and I imagine won't work in D7. The easiest way would be to just copy the `standard` profile into a new folder, go through and rename everything (file names, etc.) and add the extra code you need to :)

Comment: By values do you mean title? `$all_perms = module_invoke_all('permission'); $title = $all_perms[$perms[0]]['title'];`. That will give you the friendly title for the permission matching `access administration pages`

Comment: Thanks, where do I place this snippet?

Comment: Nevermind :) I found the title in the `role_permissions` table :)

Comment: If you're writing an installation profile the best place to put it is in `hook_install()`...have a look at the `standard.install` file and it should make a bit more sense